# SQL Injection when using native database logins/users

Tags: sql, database, authentication, code-injection

When developing an application where users connect with their native database logins, I don't need to care about SQL injection right? The reason being the users can execute any SQL they want anyway. (There are places where admins execute CREATE LOGIN and CREATE USER statements and these have to be dynamically built.) I'm talking about a native Windows application on the LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, SQL injection is a possibility to execute SQL, so with the SQL shell access, everything required for "SQL injection" is already authorized. However you still need to care if users run as non administrators, probably being restricted which tables they can access, and your system sends some additional SQL commands while logged in with higher rights (create user, etc). Use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for such a code.

Comment: The application will only connect with the user's own account at all times. Users will be in roles which have appropriate privileges assigned. In SQL Server dynamic SQL always executes under the context of the connected user even if it's in a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you are building a web application, and using users' database credentials to connect to the database, yes, you do need to worry about SQL injection.

Most databases restrict permissions based on objects - tables, views, stored procedures etc. So, a user logged in as "Bob" might have access to table "sales", but not table "payments".

The database does not restrict access to rows in tables (for instance). So, a user connected as "Bob" who can exploit a SQL injection bug in your code can delete every record in the "sales" table. You probably don't want that.

If user "Bob" also has direct SQL access, they could, of course, simply run that statement at a SQL command line - but usually, web applications are available where direct SQL access is not. Your web app may be put on the intranet to begin with, but you can't guarantee that won't be opened up in the future.

Given how easy it is to prevent SQL injection attacks when you're building the app, and what a pain it is to fix them later on, I see no real reason not to prevent them in the first place.

Comment: It's a LAN application which directly connects to the database. Appropriate permissions are granted to the roles each user will be in the DBA.

Comment: I'm only concerned about statements where I have no choice but to use dynamic SQL. Everything else is either through an ORM or is parameterised.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, "SQL injection" is a common misconception.
Being unable to *properly format* their queries, folks invented an "sql injection" thing as an excuse.
While properly formatted query will serve 2 purposes at once:

- it will always be syntactically correct, no matter what data sent in.
- as a side effect it would be invulnerable to that notorious "SQL injection" thing.

I doubt you want your queries to fail because of some unexpected symbol. So, no matter of some "injection", you have to properly format it. But once formatted, there will be no injection anyway. So, you have to concern about format, not injections.

I also have a feeling that letting users to login with database credentials is not quite a good idea.

Comment: There are several commands that don't accept parameters and only accept strings.